# Redirecting in nginx results in errors

Tags: nginx

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04, nginx, WordPress

WordPress is running fine at https://www.example.org. In addition, the following rule is defined to direct http to https:

```
server {
  if ($host = www.example.org) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.org;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

With this, a user's request to http://www.example.org automatically gets redirected to https://www.example.org.

Now, I am trying to define a rule such that https://example.org can also be redirected to https://www.example.org.

Here is my new nginx rule:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name example.org;
  return 301 https://www.example.org$request_uri;
}
```

However, this seems results in breaking the whole site. Even https://www.example.org, that was working fine earlier, gives an error that "this site can't be reached."

This is the last error from nginx error.log:

no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: blah, server: 0.0.0.0:443

To recap,

```
https://www.example.org works fine
http://www.example.org properly gets redirected to https://www.example.com
https://example.org does not work. It should also have been redirected to https://www.example.org
```

Can someone please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong? Regards.

Comment: You need to define `SSL` certificates in the `.conf`, which certs are you using? I'm guessing `letsencrypt` by the commented lines. It should have a path set in there which you need to include.

Comment: Do you want every request/uri to use SSL? Could be much simpler if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified if you need all URIs to redirect, but here are several options. Make sure you are restarting the nginx service after these changes.

**Specific URIs**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

**All URIs**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The trick was to add both example.org and www.example.org together.

Comment: @Peter Had a feeling that was the key to it. Would you update the title to be more specific in case someone else has the same issue? Something such as "Redirecting multiple URIs in nginx results in error."